# React Router add different layout to 404 page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is the component:

```
function App() {

  const Main = () => {
    return (
      <section className="app_section">
        <div className="navbar_container">
          <Navbar />
        </div>

        <div className="pages_container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashboardPage />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
            <Route path="terms" element={<TermsPage />} />
            <Route path="privacy" element={<PrivacyPage />} />
            <Route path="api" element={<Api />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  };

  const NotFound = () => {
    return <p>404</p>;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Main />} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I add a third layout to the router for 404 Not Found page I tried doing this :

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route path="/*" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
```

but it's not working due to `"/*"` hitting all links how can I mitigate that?

Comment: When you say you want a different layout are you referring to section and navbar that `Main` is rendering? You want `NotFound` to render into a different layout container?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, for simplicity I added this `const NotFound = () => { return <p>404</p>; };`

Comment: You need to handle your routes based on your requirements. `/*` is too broad and the application is working as expected. You might want to change `/*` it should ideally be "specific" rather than "generic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a `MainLayout` wrapper component that has the layout container components you desire and renders an `Outlet` for children routes. Render the `NotFound` on a `Route` *outside* the `MainLayout` route.

```
const MainLayout = () => (
  <section className="app_section">
    <div className="navbar_container">
      <Navbar />
    </div>

    <div className="pages_container">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </section>
);
```

...

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
        <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashboardPage />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
        <Route path="terms" element={<TermsPage />} />
        <Route path="privacy" element={<PrivacyPage />} />
        <Route path="api" element={<Api />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Main />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-add-different-layout-to-404-page]